# Word for culture that develops around a specific skill or task that one does

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for ideas and rituals that have developed around a skill or a task that one does?

For example, consider coffee-making or metalworking. Many people do these things as hobbies and there is a "culture" that has developed around them, where people exchange ideas of doing these things in a better or different way. For coffee-making, there is "coffee culture" and metalworking is just "metalworking".

What I am looking for is another word that could be used in the same sense as 'culture' in "coffee culture".

Comment: Why do you need a separate word when "culture" suffices?

Comment: Note that "farming" is another example.

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence to fit the word into. Until then - *craft*.

Comment: @PhilSweet 'Craft' is close to what I am looking for, but the emphasis is more on practice than theory. I think max-norton's answer is what I was looking for. 'Lore' encompasses both theory and practice. And could be used in connection with established occupations as well as more mundane tasks:
"In coffee-making lore, a portafilter is a device which..."
"In sumo lore, the dohyo-iri is a ceremony performed during..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is ***lore***, used to mean

> the body of traditional facts, anecdotes, or beliefs relating to some particular subject; chiefly with attributive noun, as *animal lore*, *bird lore*, *fairy lore*, *plant lore* ([OED, *lore* n. 1](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00135699), sense 5)

Its historical association with religious doctrine helps it encompass both knowledge and practice.